# How do i delete the last number that is being shown?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a game that has a cookie in the middle and if you click that cookie, your points increase

My problem is that once i display the points and increase it, the numbers overlap

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Cookie Clicker")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen.fill("White")
font1 =         pygame.font.Font("c:/Users/oreni/OneDrive/Masaüstü/sprites/Minecraft.        ttf", 25)
font2 = pygame.font.Font("c:/Users/oreni/OneDrive/Masaüstü/sprites/Minecraft.ttf", 30)
font3 =     pygame.font.Font("c:/Users/oreni/OneDrive/Masaüstü/sprites/Minecraft.ttf", 35)
font4 = pygame.font.Font("c:/Users/oreni/OneDrive/Masaüstü/sprites/Minecraft.        ttf", 40)
font5 = pygame.font.Font("c:/Users/oreni/OneDrive/Masaüstü/sprites/Minecraft.ttf", 45)
font6 = pygame.font.Font("c:/Users/oreni/OneDrive/Masaüstü/sprites/Minecraft.ttf", 50)
noc = 0

# Texts
nuofco = font4.render(str(noc), False, "Black")
nuofco_r = nuofco.get_rect(center = (237,80))

# Drawn Rects
cookie = pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, "Brown", (110,150,250,250))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, "Black", pygame.Rect(475,0,25,500))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if cookie.collidepoint(event.pos):
                noc += 1
        screen.blit(nuofco,nuofco_r)



    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Please give us some code to work with

Comment: PS being shown how? printed? in a list? in a dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calculating the new number I think you need to redraw everything on the screen including the background. Because everything you draw on the screen is actually drawn on top of the previous one. And everything overlaps when the background is not drawn.

And also in the main loop, the usually recommended order is to take input, update variables, draw everything. It would be better for you if you first calculate everything that needs to be calculated and then draw what needs to be drawn.

Comment: Also you used pygame.display.update() which only updates the current display surface, you need to do pygame.display.flip() to update all display surfaces

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but do i have to redraw everything? For example if a draw a rectangle do i have to redraw that rectangle in the main loop?

Comment: Yes. That's why there is a term called fps. Calculation is made for each frame and printed on the screen.

In 3D games, lights, visual effects, and even how the 3d models will look according to the position of the camera have to be calculated. Not to mention the distortions happens at the edges according to the camera's viewing angle.

Game engines actually do a lot for us.